# Selenium Webdriver v3.6.0 Not accepting chromedriver arguments - C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently updated my Selenium Webdriver to v3.6.0 and now none of my arguments for my chromedriver are working. If I was to roll back to Selenium Webdriver v3.5.0 the given arguments would once again work.

This is my code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"--C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium", options);
```

I have tried to find a solution to this but have had no luck.

My chromedriver version: 2.33

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember what the current version is supposed to be ... have you updated Selenium, Chrome, and Chrome drivers to all the latest and greatest?

Comment: So all my chrome (v61), chromedriver (v2.33) and Selenium (v3.6.0) are up to date.

Comment: Hmm.. it's possible with all the recent updates that it got broken. You might post a bug on the Selenium site for the Chromedriver and see what they say.